# Why $('.myClass').on("input propertychange", function() {}) is always called before $(document).on("input propertychange", ".myClass", function() {))?

Tags: jquery, events

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/us6ne9og/) a working example:

```
$(document).on("input propertychange", ".myClass", function () {
    $('#result').append("first<br />");
});

$('.myClass').on("input propertychange", function () {
  $('#result').append("second<br />");
});
```

Even if I define the `first` block of code before the `second`, it always print `second` first.

Why? And how can I assure they will be executed in cascade?

Comment: You can put your working examples **here, on site** using Stack Snippets. [here's how](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Comment: think how bubbling works..... Starts at the top and works its way down. The one is attached directly to the element, the other is attached to the document and than sees what was clicked.

Answer (score 6):

Because this is how event handling works. Events first go through a *capture* phase from the window through the document to the target element, and then *bubble* from the target element to the window.

Your first `on` call attaches a `click` handler on `document` that, when called, will check to see if the event passed through any elements matching `.myClass` between the end target and `document` and, if so, calls your handler. Your second `on` call attaches the handler directly to the matching element(s). In both cases, you're hooking the bubbling phase (jQuery doesn't support hooking the capture phase). So the handler on the element itself is called before a matching delegated hander on the document. (Technically, when the event is *at* the target element, it's in the *target* phase, not capture or bubbling. But both capture and bubbling handlers are caled — and in that order — on the target element.)

Here's a great all-in-one diagram from the old [DOM3 Events spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/):

[image]

You can find details in the current [DOM4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#events).

Although jQuery doesn't support the capture phase, [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) does on compliant browsers (so, not IE8 and earlier, which didn't have capture or `addEventListener`). The third argument to `addEventListener` lets you decide whether you want capture (`true`) or bubbling (`false`); it defaults to `false` (on really modern systems, the third argument can be an object with various flags).

Here's an example showing an event in all its phases:

```js
// See: https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-event-none
const eventPhases = ["NONE", "CAPTURING_PHASE", "AT_TARGET", "BUBBLING_PHASE"];

function captureHandler(e) {
  console.log("captureHandler: " + eventPhases[e.eventPhase] + " on " + this.id);
}
function bubbleHandler(e) {
  console.log("bubbleHandler:  " + eventPhases[e.eventPhase] + " on " + this.id);
}

function hookBoth(element) {
  element.addEventListener("click", captureHandler, true);
  element.addEventListener("click", bubbleHandler, false);
}

hookBoth(document.getElementById("outer"));
hookBoth(document.getElementById("middle"));
hookBoth(document.getElementById("target"));
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="target">Click Me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```